# Puppet : How to get logs in to the same terminal in agent side

Tags: shell, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I am executing a shell script in the puppet agent side. If I execute the same shell script in my local machine it will print several log messages to terminal. But when I execute it in the puppet agent it does not print any log into the agent terminal.

How can I print the logs of the shell script when I run it using puppet?

I am using following command to execute the shell script.

```
exec { "strating":
    user    => 'root',
    environment => 'JAVA_HOME=/home/malintha/jdk1.6.0',
    path        => $command_path,
    command => "/pathToShellScript/myScript.sh",
    logoutput => true,
    timeout => 3600,
    require => Exec['another goal'],
}
```

Note: I set `logoutput => true`

Comment: How are you invoking `puppet`?

Comment: "puppet agent --test" in my root

Comment: Can you make a trivial manifest of that `exec { }` resource and run it through `puppet apply -dv`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `--debug` flag to the puppet command.

```
 puppet agent --test --debug
```

Or alternatively you can also set the `loglevel` metaparameter to `info` or `notice`:

```
 exec { 'starting':
   path      => $command_path,
   command   => '/path/to/script.sh',
   logoutput => true,
   loglevel  => info
 }
```

See the below output:

```
 [~]$ puppet apply --verbose test.pp
 Notice: Compiled catalog for dpsmqm009.local in environment production in 0.03 seconds
 Info: Applying configuration version '1403302144'
 Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[starting]/returns: testing
 Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[starting]/returns: testing again
 Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[starting]/returns: testing some more
 Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[starting]/returns: executed successfully
 Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.20 seconds
```

#### Reference

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#loglevel